# Using PHP in Aptana Studio 3 I get "No PHP executables defined"

Tags: php, xampp, wamp, aptana3

I'm a long time hobbyist using M/S Visual Studio but am trying to get away from ASP .Net. I have installed Aptana Studio 3 and get everything working on an HTML5 web page except PHP. The test website consists of a single index.html, a single javascript to access the PHP and a single PHP page to respond to the javascript.

I uploaded the 3 files to my domain's server and it worked correctly. Using Aptana 3, I put the 3 files in a new PHP project but I get "No PHP executables defined" when I try to preview the project. I searched the web but get no help.

Some info seems to say PHP interpreter should already be installed with Aptana, others say you have to do it separately. Still, others say I have to install WAMP. I was unable to decipher the Aptana website documentation to resolve the problem.

Any help on how to set up / configure Aptana Studio 3 to properly preview an Html5 website with PHP would be appreciated.

Comment: So do you have PHP interpreter on your local host?

Comment: I have copied all the PHP files from the zip file to directory "c:/php".

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of whether Aptanta Studio comes with PHP or not, download and install the latest version of PHP just to be on the safe side:  http://php.net/downloads.php

Then in Aptana Studio, go to Preferences -> Aptanta Studio -> Editors -> PHP -> PHP Interpreters and specify your PHP installation details.

Then try it again and see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I have "installed" PHP 5.4 in directory c:/php and listed the interperter as "c:/php/php.exe" . I have also installed Xampp. I no longer get the "No PHP executables defined"  but the php file still does nothing. I made a very simple "index.php" that has the normal html5 boilerplate and one simple php echo statement. The HTML is processed but the php is simply ignored. I also  installed NetBeans but no better luck with it ("localhost:8000 not found"). Any ideas or maybe you can point me to a tutorial someplace with step-by-step instructions. Thanks.

Comment: A little more progress: ran the following cmd line:

Comment: A little more progress: ran the following cmd line: "php -S localhost:8000" and it actually worked, but only if I ran it from "C:/php" directry and then with a ".php" file in the same directry using NetBeans. Still haven't made any progress with Aptana. I can't believe that NetBeans dos not automatically start the server when you select it in the run configuration dialog. Did I miss something?

Comment: I believe for Xamp you have to put your Aptana Studio projects under the Apache folder "/htdocs", and check that the conf\httpd.conf file has a setting to look in that folder for your projects (I think it's called DirectoryFile or something).  There should also be php settings in httpd.conf as well. 

I have Aptana Studio 3 working with WampServer after similar troubles.  I just installed WampServer, then moved my projects under the /www folder of WampServer and everything just works.

If you are trying to change the port number to run Apache under, you can just change the port in httpd.conf.